# return custom json response using strongly typed model

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

My response model class

```
public class MyModel
{
   public Tuple<string, string> Data{ get; set; }
}

var data = new MyModel
{
   Data = Tuple.Create("error", "12345");
};
```

which results in the following json response

```
 {
  "data": {
    "item1": "error",
    "item2": "12345"
  }
}
```

What I want is to create a response as follows

```
 "data" : [{ "error" : "12345" }]
```

These `item1` and `item2` are of course dynamic data and it can be anything of type string. I'm saying this because I cannot simply decorate the properties with `JsonProperty` attribute.

Comment: Is there a reason it is a tuple? Seems like an array of keyvaluepair would serve you better.

Comment: @BenMatthews `KeyValuePair` will not be serializied to needed format by default.

Comment: Am I missing some tricky part here. Why use Tuple when the desired output is something else.

Comment: @GuruStron Ah, you are absolutely right. My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need either to implement custom serializer for your tuple or change your model to represent the desired structure. If you don't want to create some specific types for your inner data you can leverage `Dictionary` serialization convention:

```cs
public class MyModel
{
   public Dictionary<string, string>[] Data{ get; set; }
}
```

And creation:

```
var data = new MyModel
{
    Data = new[]
    {
        new Dictionary<string, string> { { "error", "message" } }
    }
};
```

Or make your field into array of objects and create anonymous ones:

```cs
public class MyModel
{
   public object[] Data{ get; set; }
}
```

```
var data = new MyModel
{
    Data = new[]
    {
        new { error = "message" } 
    }
}
```